# AngularJS - Lodash html capitalize usage

Tags: html, angularjs, lodash

I am using Lodash - angularJS.

```
_.capitalize('angularjs') from controller working for me.
```

`Output:` `Angularjs`

And I am using translator. i.e., `angularjs` loading from translate

In main controller getting current language

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
$translate.use(language);
```

Using below config function

```
function configFunction($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider
        .translations('en-US', {
            angularjs: "angularjs",
            java: "java"
        })
        .translations('en-UK', {
            angularjs: "angularjs",
            java: "java"
        });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en-US');
}

angular
    .module('angularjsApp')
    .config(configFunction)
```

I wanted to use this from html. How can I use?

Comment: You should update your question to state your requirement that you want to first use `translate` filter and then do `_.capitalize()` on it

Comment: have you seen my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

create a filter like this and use pipe (|) in binding

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('common', [])
        .filter('capitalize', capitalize);

    capitalize.$inject = [];
    function capitalize() {
        return capitalizeFilter;

        ////////////////
        function capitalizeFilter(text) {
            return _.capitalize(text);
        };
    }

})();
```

and in html

```
<div>{{"angularjs" | capitalize}}</div>
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yuwuzewuya/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jeetendra Chauhan. Can we do without filter?

Comment: @Donthamsettivbhadrarao use _ in a filter is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty vague question. If I understand then you want to display the above in html using Angular data-binding, ie. bind a variable to your html element and run the Lodash method on that variable.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Somevar: <input type="text" ng-model="myVar">
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    // load your Lodash module
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        // bind a dynamic variable to your html
        $scope.myVar = _.capitalize('angularjs');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Devan Accountero. Any filter is available directly for us to do it from html?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to do this, you should pass the result value to your scope but if you need this just add Lodash to your $scope like this:

```js
// controller
$scope._ = _;
```

```html
{{_.capitalize('angularjs') | translate}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Germando. I wanted to use this with translator. {{_.capitalize('angularjs' | translate)}} not working for me. How can I use?

Comment: Try this {{_.capitalize('angularjs') | translate}}

Comment: Could you please provide some code showing how your translate filter is set up?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution

```
angular.module('app', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
.config(function ($translateProvider) {
   $translateProvider.translations('en', {
     Angularjs: 'angularjs'
   });
})
.constant('_', window._)
.filter('capitalizeIt', ['_', function(_) {
    return function(str) {
        return _.capitalize(str)
    }
}]);
```

Now in your view

```
<h1>Hello {{'angularjs' | translate | capitalizeIt }}!</h1>
```

Complete working demo on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y47oB4iu1MrbcJFmuo2y?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kachhalimbu. If it's {{ 'angularjs' | uppercase | translate}}, first which filter will execute? Is there any left/right precedence..

Comment: It will be left to right i.e. first capitalize then it's result will be passed to translate

Comment: have updated my answer to solve your issue you stated in another comment.